# ::LoadLibraryW fails with ERROR_PROCESS_MODE_NOT_BACKGROUND

Tags: windows, loadlibrary, libpq

I have built postgres windows libpq.dll following the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/install-windows-full.html. I was able to build libpq.dll but when I am using the dll in my code it fails. Below is the sample code

```
moduleHandle = ::LoadLibraryW( module );
```

When I googled i got below info from microsoft

```
ERROR_PROCESS_MODE_NOT_BACKGROUND

403 (0x193)

The process is not in background processing mode.
```

DO i need to enable any flag while building libpq.dll? Need  help with this